# hello-jni NDK sample - ndk-build fails

Tags: android, android-ndk

I am following the steps on http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/overview.html to build the hello-jni sample, however when I get to Step 2 to run

```
cd $NDK-ROOT/samples/hello-jni
$NDK-ROOT/ndk-build
```

in the Cygwin command prompt, I receive the following error messages:

```
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
/bin/sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
Android NDK: Host awk tool is outdated. Please define HOST_AWK to point to Gawk
or Nawk !
```

I have Cygwin 1.7.9, Gnu Make 3.8.2, and Gawk 3.1.8 on my Windows machine, along with the r5b release of the Android NDK.
I also have set the HOST_AWK environment variable, which points to my Gawk folder.

Unfortunatley the sample cannot run successfully without this step, (if I run hello-jni, I immediately receive an UnsatisfiedLinkError exception).

Below is the portion of the init.mk file on my machine (found in NDK_ROOT/build/core) which creates this error:

```
# Location of all awk scripts we use
BUILD_AWK := $(NDK_ROOT)/build/awk

AWK_TEST := $(shell $(HOST_AWK) -f $(BUILD_AWK)/check-awk.awk)
$(call ndk_log,Host awk test returned: $(AWK_TEST))
ifneq ($(AWK_TEST),Pass)
$(call __ndk_info,Host awk tool is outdated. Please define HOST_AWK to point to Gawk or     Nawk !)
$(call __ndk_error,Aborting.)
endif
```

Thank-you for your help

Comment: try updating your awk tool. Seems to an an outdated version (perhaps).

Comment: Had same issue,
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8384213/android-ndk-revision-7-host-awk-tool-is-outdated-error


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8384213/android-ndk-revision-7-host-awk-tool-is-outdated-error

Comment: Same issue on Cygwin - Awk 4.0.0

Comment: The problem in this case seems to be that $(NDK_ROOT) gives a null result since my root is stored in $NDK_ROOT (without parenthesis).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out there was an apostrophe in my HOST_AWK path, which was causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your awk tool. Seems to an an outdated version (perhaps). Also ensure that NDK root is defined to where you have your NDK source and ensure that your awk tool is located in the build directory of your NDK Source.

> NDK_ROOT

Try settings this environment variable to where your NDK root is. Whenever this is defined (Typically at the top)

Comment: The awk tool I have is Gawk version 3.1.8, which is the latest version. This is also the version provided with the Cygwin install. My NDK_ROOT environment variable is pointing to my android-ndk-r5b folder location, and my HOST_AWK environment variable is pointing to gawk.exe - but this came with the Cygwin install, so is in my Cygwin\bin folder.

Comment: Should I install Gawk again separately, to place it in my NDK_ROOT/build folder? Currently NDK_ROOT/build contains:
awk/
core/
gmsl/
tools/

Comment: I'm not sure about the specifics.. but I would expect that all the awk tools would be in that directory.

Comment: I copied the gawk executables to the NDK_ROOT/build/awk directory (which currently only contains .awk files) and the same error persists.

Comment: did you remember to see the NDK_ROOT variable to where YOUR ndk toolset is?

Comment: Yes, my NDK_ROOT environment variable is pointing to my android-ndk-r5b folder.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `HOST_AWK=gawk.exe`, just do `HOST_AWK=gawk`

Comment: I just updated my environment variable to reflect this, unfortunately I still receive the same error.

Answer (score 0):

reference
https://stackoverflow.com/q/8121153/411522

mine worked fine now.what to do is: just rename the prebuilt awk in ndk