# problems with Android NDK-7 and AWK

Tags: android, android-ndk

I am having problems with the latest Android NDK:

```
ligi@ligid:~$ ndk-build 
/home/ligi/bin/android-ndk/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/awk: 1: ELF: not found
/home/ligi/bin/android-ndk/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/awk: 4: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")
Android NDK: Host 'awk' tool is outdated. Please define HOST_AWK to point to Gawk or Nawk !    
/home/ligi/bin/android-ndk/build/core/init.mk:258: *** Android NDK: Aborting.    .  Stop.

ligi@ligid:~$ `echo $HOST_AWK --v`
GNU Awk 3.1.7
```

I am on stock ubuntu ant totally out of ideas and good keywords for searches

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I also had this issue and found this Japanese site with similar problems:

http://d.hatena.ne.jp/yohpapa/20111113/1321198570

I hope I puzzled out the Google Translated stuff correctly - in any case, basically in the new NDK install, find this directory:

```
..../android-ndk-r7/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin
```

and rename the file "awk" there to something else like "awk_"

I did this and ndk_build now works for me. If I am reading the make files right there is a file called init.mk which replaces your HOST_AWK with the prebuilt value if it finds it...so renaming the awk file there defaults back to your gawk.

Hope that helps

Kibi

Comment: This solutions apply when you are running a 32 bits version of Linux. This problem does not happen on a 64 Linux distribution.

Comment: Note that on Windows, the equivalent worked for me, except I had to rename the file awk.exe inside the prebuilt/windows/bin folder.

Comment: @Ixx - I imagine this info is out of date by now anyway - there's probably a new NDK. If you are using the old one, make sure your system has some other awk or gawk installed

Comment: Yes, I solved this, although I don't remember how. But I gave up after the next ~4 installation problems. I guess I'll try it on Linux the next time.

Answer (score 6):

The problem is the executable ndk/prebuild/linux-x86/awk is compiled for x86_64, it's not run in a 32 bit kernel

Answer (score 1):

1. Update your local awk.
2. Remove the awk in android-ndk itself.

This should resolve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Go to your `<ndk_dir>\build\core\` and open `init.mk` in a text editor, e.g. notepad

Replace the following line

```
HOST_AWK := $(wildcard $(HOST_PREBUILT)/awk$(HOST_EXEEXT))
```

with

```
ifeq ($(HOST_OS),cygwin)
      HOST_AWK := $(wildcard $(HOST_PREBUILT)/gawk$(HOST_EXEEXT))
else
      HOST_AWK := $(wildcard $(HOST_PREBUILT)/awk$(HOST_EXEEXT))
endif
```

@Tod : Thanks, I used your hint here

That works.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem running from eclipse on windows with cygwin and NDK8.

I had to add `HOST_AWK` as an environment variable under project properties -> c/c++ Build -> Environment with the value `/cygdrive/[cygwin installdir]/bin/gawk`

(As well as having to set the c/c++ build command to `bash -c ndk-build`)

Answer (score 0):

I was having a problem with different versions of awk on windows. This change uses the cygwin version of awk from a cygwin console and the prebuilt version from a dos console.

Add to init.mk:

```
ifeq ($(HOST_OS),cygwin)
       HOST_AWK := /bin/awk
endif
```