# Android NDK revision 7 Host 'awk' tool is outdated error

Tags: android, android-ndk

I am getting "Android NDK: Host 'awk' tool is outdated. Please define HOST_AWK to point to Gawk or Nawk !" error on latest android ndk revision 7.

Comment: If you added a fix in ndk-7 by adding a `HOST_AWK` env variable, remove it before running ndk-8 or you will get the same error.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Solved the problem.

Solution:

> 1. Navigate to ../android-ndk-r7/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin
> 2. Rename the file awk to awk_

Imoprtant thing to note on windows machine:

ndk revision 7 onwards, ndk source can be built without cygwin, ie.., 
instead of calling ndk-build command from inside a Cygwin shell, you should call run ndk-build.cmd inside a MSDOS command window.

---

It works because probably ndk-build first tries to use a locally defined, but old (at least for Linux), version of awk. By renaming it, we make it unreachable by such command, so, apparently, ndk-build calls the system-wide awk.

Comment: OMG! IT WRKS! Android is crazy :)

Comment: but there is no awk file in my pc

Comment: This solution still works!! Thanks you so much

Answer (score 14):

This Solution (from Santhosh) works also under windows:

1. Navigate to ../android-ndk-r7/prebuilt/windows/bin Rename the file
2. rename awk.exe to awk_.exe

Answer (score 3):

I think the problem is `$(HOST_AWK)` not defined correctly and local prebuild `awk.exe` doesn't work. Thus prebuild `awk.exe` should be deleted or renamed and use `gawk` if `awk` is not defined.

To solve this problem:

1 - Rename `<drive>\android-ndk\prebuilt\windows\bin\awk.exe` to `<drive>\android-ndk\prebuilt\windows\bin\awk_.exe`.

2 - Open `<drive>\android-ndk\build\core\init.mk`

Replace

```
HOST_AWK := $(strip $(HOST_AWK))
ifndef HOST_AWK
    HOST_AWK := awk
endif
```

with

```
HOST_AWK := $(strip $(HOST_AWK))
ifndef HOST_AWK
    HOST_AWK := gawk
endif
```

Note that `awk` renamed to `gawk`.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this japanese post: http://d.hatena.ne.jp/yohpapa/20111113/1321198570

They explain how to solve your problem. Is in japanese, but the commands are legible =)

Hope this helps...

Comment: Thanks for to you man.As I am able to understand Japanese it's easy to solve.

Answer (score 1):

I was having a problem with different versions of awk on windows. This change uses the cygwin version of awk from a cygwin console and the prebuilt version from a dos console.

Add to init.mk:

```
ifeq ($(HOST_OS),cygwin)
       HOST_AWK := /bin/awk
endif
```