# how to run .sh file on windows using cygwin?

Tags: linux, windows, cygwin

I am beginner of `cygwin` terminal. I am trying to run `*.sh` file on windows 8 using command `./file_name.sh`, but it gives error given below....

`Using prebuilt externals`

`ERROR: Cannot find 'make' program. Please install Cygwin make package`
`or define the GNUMAKE variable to point to it.`

I have installed `cygwin` in `F` drive, I google this error and set the variable path in `computer properties > advance system properties > variable environment > path >edit` and variable path is `;F:\cygwin\bin`
But does not work. How can i solve this problem??

Here is my script

```
`# set params`
NDK_ROOT=/cygdrive/f/Android/android-ndk-r9b
COCOS2DX_ROOT=/cygdrive/f/Android/cocos2d-2.0-rc2-x-2.0.1
GAME_ROOT=$COCOS2DX_ROOT/molatx
GAME_ANDROID_ROOT=$GAME_ROOT/proj.android
RESOURCE_ROOT=$GAME_ROOT/Resources

buildexternalsfromsource=

usage(){
cat << EOF
usage: $0 [options]

Build C/C++ native code using Android NDK

OPTIONS:
   -s   Build externals from source
   -h   this help
EOF
}

while getopts "s" OPTION; do
    case "$OPTION" in
        s)
            buildexternalsfromsource=1
            ;;
        h)
            usage
            exit 0
            ;;
    esac
done

`# make sure assets is exist`
if [ -d $GAME_ANDROID_ROOT/assets ]; then
    rm -rf $GAME_ANDROID_ROOT/assets
fi

mkdir $GAME_ANDROID_ROOT/assets

`# copy resources`
for file in $RESOURCE_ROOT/*
do
    if [ -d "$file" ]; then
        cp -rf "$file" $GAME_ANDROID_ROOT/assets
    fi

    if [ -f "$file" ]; then
        cp "$file" $GAME_ANDROID_ROOT/assets
    fi
done

`# copy icons (if they exist)`
file=$GAME_ANDROID_ROOT/assets/Icon-72.png
if [ -f "$file" ]; then
    cp $file $GAME_ANDROID_ROOT/res/drawable-hdpi/icon.png
fi
file=$GAME_ANDROID_ROOT/assets/Icon-48.png
if [ -f "$file" ]; then
    cp $file $GAME_ANDROID_ROOT/res/drawable-mdpi/icon.png
fi
file=$GAME_ANDROID_ROOT/assets/Icon-32.png
if [ -f "$file" ]; then
    cp $file $GAME_ANDROID_ROOT/res/drawable-ldpi/icon.png
fi


if [[ $buildexternalsfromsource ]]; then
    echo "Building external dependencies from source"
    $NDK_ROOT/ndk-build -C $GAME_ANDROID_ROOT \
        NDK_MODULE_PATH=${COCOS2DX_ROOT}:${COCOS2DX_ROOT}/cocos2dx/platform/third_party/android/source
else
    echo "Using prebuilt externals"
    $NDK_ROOT/ndk-build -C $GAME_ANDROID_ROOT \
        NDK_MODULE_PATH=${COCOS2DX_ROOT}:${COCOS2DX_ROOT}/cocos2dx/platform/third_party/android/prebuilt
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to install make package using cygwin "setup.exe" wizard.
Check what programming language is your script compiling because the compiler of that language  will be also dependencies of your script.

Probably you will need to install some libraries too.

Comment: @LASIAF I can't tell you unless you post a copy of your script. It seems to me that your script is trying to compile something so you need to have the compiler it is using and any library which is a dependency of the program being compiled.

Comment: # set params
NDK_ROOT=/cygdrive/f/Android/android-ndk-r9b
COCOS2DX_ROOT=/cygdrive/f/Android/cocos2d-2.0-rc2-x-2.0.1
GAME_ROOT=$COCOS2DX_ROOT/molatx
GAME_ANDROID_ROOT=$GAME_ROOT/proj.android
RESOURCE_ROOT=$GAME_ROOT/Resources

buildexternalsfromsource=

usage(){
cat << EOF
usage: $0 [options]

Build C/C++ native code using Android NDK

OPTIONS:
   -s Build externals from source
   -h this help
EOF
}

while getopts "s" OPTION; do
 case "$OPTION" in
  s)
   buildexternalsfromsource=1
   ;;
  h)
   usage
   exit 0
   ;;
 esac
done

Comment: # make sure assets is exist
if [ -d $GAME_ANDROID_ROOT/assets ]; then
    rm -rf $GAME_ANDROID_ROOT/assets
fi

mkdir $GAME_ANDROID_ROOT/assets

# copy resources
for file in $RESOURCE_ROOT/*
do
    if [ -d "$file" ]; then
        cp -rf "$file" $GAME_ANDROID_ROOT/assets
    fi

    if [ -f "$file" ]; then
        cp "$file" $GAME_ANDROID_ROOT/assets
    fi
done

Comment: # copy icons (if they exist)
file=$GAME_ANDROID_ROOT/assets/Icon-72.png
if [ -f "$file" ]; then
 cp $file $GAME_ANDROID_ROOT/res/drawable-hdpi/icon.png
fi
file=$GAME_ANDROID_ROOT/assets/Icon-48.png
if [ -f "$file" ]; then
 cp $file $GAME_ANDROID_ROOT/res/drawable-mdpi/icon.png
fi
file=$GAME_ANDROID_ROOT/assets/Icon-32.png
if [ -f "$file" ]; then
 cp $file $GAME_ANDROID_ROOT/res/drawable-ldpi/icon.png
fi

Comment: if [[ $buildexternalsfromsource ]]; then
    echo "Building external dependencies from source"
    $NDK_ROOT/ndk-build -C $GAME_ANDROID_ROOT \
        NDK_MODULE_PATH=${COCOS2DX_ROOT}:${COCOS2DX_ROOT}/cocos2dx/platform/third_party/android/source
else
    echo "Using prebuilt externals"
    $NDK_ROOT/ndk-build -C $GAME_ANDROID_ROOT \
        NDK_MODULE_PATH=${COCOS2DX_ROOT}:${COCOS2DX_ROOT}/cocos2dx/platform/third_party/android/prebuilt
fi

Comment: @Fransico Perez Hidalgo
code is in parts. comment 1= part 1,comment 2= part 2,comment 3= part 3,comment 4 = part 4,
sorry for poor formatting.

Comment: @LASIAF You should had eddited your question with the scsipt. I'll try to compose your script.

Comment: Type ls command in your cmd to check cmd is properly install or not

Comment: @LASIAF , have you read this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10481132/cygwin-for-android-ndk-programming) stackoverflow question?

Answer (score 0):

Your Windows system path is different to your Cygwin path. If you install the required packages using cygwin setup they will already be available in your $PATH.

Run cygwin setup an install:  make , automake , gcc , gcc-c++