# cygwin installation and OCR / scan

Tags: android, eclipse, cygwin, ocr, tesseract

Iam developing an android mobile application to scan text  and save the details to phone. Iam developing  in windows , using eclipse and whilst doing research I came across this article that pointed to the fact that an installation of cygwin is required  to develop such an application. Cygwin however is very large after 3 hours of downloading it had only downloaded about 6 of the required 12gigabytes. I would jus like to know where Iam going wrong with cygwin ,  whether its mandatory that cygwin is installed and if that is the case which specific packages should be installed??

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

From ndk r7, we don't need cygwin anymore. Just set NDK path in system environment then run `ndk-build` command and it should work. For more detail, look [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10484866/719212).

You can follow [this tutorial](http://gaut.am/making-an-ocr-android-app-using-tesseract/) to set up enviroment for tesseract on Android with [tess-two](https://github.com/rmtheis/tess-two) library. These commands are used for build tess-two:

```
cd <project-directory>/tess-two
ndk-build
android update project --path .
ant release
```