# jni/Android.mk:8:curlLib/packages/Android/Android.mk: No such file or directory

Tags: android, c++, c, curl, android-ndk

I have never built curl with Android.

Pre-requisites : I am using Android Studio 2.1.2 
I am using NDK , non-experimental way
I have Source code of the curl-7.49.1 library inside my jni folder in curlLib directory
ExtLibCurl is folder/directory inside my application jni folder, which has source code downloaded from 
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/curl/+/e6f2b03027b5feb92b30f5d47801ec3fabe9fd95

Can check Android.mk for cURL and other files there.

Updating the files according to the comments in the question.

Following is my Android.mk file

```
JNI_DIR := $(call my-dir)

LOCAL_PATH:= $(JNI_DIR)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

include $(LOCAL_PATH)/ExtLibCurl/Android.mk

# Build main library as shared library.
LOCAL_PATH := $(JNI_DIR)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(LOCAL_PATH)/ExtLibCurl/include/curl
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(LOCAL_PATH)/ExtLibCurl/lib

FILE_LIST += $(wildcard $(LOCAL_PATH)/ExtLibCurl/src/*.c)

LOCAL_MODULE := ndksampleapp
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(FILE_LIST:$(LOCAL_PATH)/%=%)

LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := ExtLibCurl

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Application.mk

```
APP_ABI := all
APP_STL    := gnustl_static
APP_CFLAGS += -std=gnu++11
APP_OPTIM  := debug
LOCAL_CPP_FEATURES += exceptions

NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION := 4.9
```

Is my way of building curl's Android.mk is correct?

when I do ndk-build in src\main path I am getting following error

```
    [arm64-v8a] Compile        : ndksampleapp <= curlutil.c
cc1.exe: warning: command line option '-std=gnu++11' is valid for C++/ObjC++ but not for C
In file included from jni/ExtLibCurl/lib/strdup.h:24:0,
                 from jni/ExtLibCurl/src/setup.h:206,
                 from jni/ExtLibCurl/src/curlutil.c:23:
jni/ExtLibCurl/lib/setup.h:120:28: fatal error: curl/curlbuild.h: No such file or directory
 #include <curl/curlbuild.h>
                            ^
compilation terminated.
make: *** [obj/local/arm64-v8a/objs-debug/ndksampleapp/ExtLibCurl/src/curlutil.o] Error 1
```

If I remove FILE_LIST += $(wildcard $(LOCAL_PATH)/ExtLibCurl/src/*.c) no cURL files are getting build.

Comment: As a quick test change the relative path include of curlLib's android.mk to a full absolute path.  If that works then the problem becomes working out the correct relative path knowing that the rest of the build is correct..

Comment: Hey @RichardCritten thanks for the response, but its not working aborting giving following error : Android NDK: Trying to define local module 'curl' in jni/curlLib/packages/Android/Android.mk.
Android NDK: But this module was already defined by jni/curlLib/packages/Android/Android.mk.
C:/Users/m1035325/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/build//../build/core/build-module.mk:34: *** Android NDK: Aborting.    .  Stop. I even tried with fully qualified path.

Comment: What is to downvote in the question?

Comment: Re downvote - have no idea - up-voted you back to 0.

Comment: @RichardCritten thanks :)

Comment: you are including external makefile, but not making most of it. You can read more about modules here: http://web.guohuiwang.com/technical-notes/androidndk1#5-4-using-code-include-code-to-embed-code-mk-code-files  in short: remove curl from FILE_LIST, and add `LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := libcurl` before `include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)`

Comment: Hey @V-master thanks for the inputs. I have checked the link you shared. I made changes in my Android.mk Added LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := ExtLibCurl before include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY) and removed curl from FILE_LIST and included curl's Android.mk like this : include $(LOCAL_PATH)/ExtLibCurl/Android.mk now ndk-bui;ld not giving any error but still its not compiling any curl file. and Cygwin is not needed right? as per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10481132/cygwin-for-android-ndk-programming. Can you please point out where I am doing wrong? I am also checking from my side.

Comment: can you update the question with new changes and possible error? regarding cygwin, I presume it should work, never used without it.

Comment: @V-master Please check , I updated question with file changes , and possible error too.

Comment: `ExtLibCurl/Android.mk` has the line `LOCAL_MODULE:= libcurl` - this is a name of that module and this name must be used in `LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES` (not name of folder) - then curl will build without mentioning it in FILE_LIST. ps. you have deleted your own source files from FILE_LIST

Comment: ExtLibCurl/Android.mk has the line LOCAL_MODULE := curl
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := libcurl If I am not wrong. So my directory in jni should have name libcurl and so includes for .h files will also change in Android.mk according to that , is it correct? means LOCAL_C_INCLUDES variable. I did all these changes removed FILE_LIST its building .so but not showing message that it is compiling curl C/C++ files.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122170/discussion-between-v-master-and-adiatand).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yours `Android.mk` file should look like this:

```
JNI_DIR := $(call my-dir)

LOCAL_PATH:= $(JNI_DIR)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

include $(LOCAL_PATH)/ExtLibCurl/Android.mk

# Build main library as shared library.
LOCAL_PATH := $(JNI_DIR)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(LOCAL_PATH)/ExtLibCurl/include
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(LOCAL_PATH)/ExtLibCurl/lib

# !!! place list of YOUR sources to this variable !!!
FILE_LIST += $(wildcard $(LOCAL_PATH)/src/*.c) 

LOCAL_MODULE := ndksampleapp
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(FILE_LIST:$(LOCAL_PATH)/%=%)

LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := libcurl
LOCAL_LDLIBS += -lz

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

name of the module don't need to match its directory name.

From `ExtLibCurl/Android.mk` you must uncomment the `BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY` part, and you can also remove all part with creating executable curl (lines 74+), that is the file will looks like this:

```
# Google Android makefile for curl and libcurl
#
# Place the curl source (including this makefile) into external/curl/ in the
# Android source tree.  Then build them with 'make curl' or just 'make libcurl'
# from the Android root. Tested with Android 1.5
#
# Note: you must first create a curl_config.h file by running configure in the
# Android environment. The only way I've found to do this is tricky. Perform a
# normal Android build with libcurl in the source tree, providing the target
# "showcommands" to make. The build will eventually fail (because curl_config.h
# doesn't exist yet), but the compiler commands used to build curl will be
# shown. Now, from the external/curl/ directory, run curl's normal configure
# command with flags that match what Android itself uses. This will mean
# putting the compiler directory into the PATH, putting the -I, -isystem and
# -D options into CPPFLAGS, putting the -m, -f, -O and -nostdlib options into
# CFLAGS, and putting the -Wl, -L and -l options into LIBS, along with the path
# to the files libgcc.a, crtbegin_dynamic.o, and ccrtend_android.o. Remember
# that the paths must be absolute since you will not be running configure from
# the same directory as the Android make.  The normal cross-compiler options
# must also be set.
#
# The end result will be a configure command that looks something like this
# (the environment variable A is set to the Android root path):
#
#  A=`realpath ../..` && \
#  PATH="$A/prebuilt/linux-x86/toolchain/arm-eabi-X/bin:$PATH" \
#  ./configure --host=arm-linux CC=arm-eabi-gcc \
#  CPPFLAGS="-I $A/system/core/include ..." \
#  CFLAGS="-fno-exceptions -Wno-multichar ..." \
#  LIB="$A/prebuilt/linux-x86/toolchain/arm-eabi-X/lib/gcc/arm-eabi/X\
#  /interwork/libgcc.a ..." \
#
# Dan Fandrich
# September 2009
LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)
common_CFLAGS := -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wunused -Winline -Wnested-externs -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wno-long-long -Wfloat-equal -Wno-multichar -Wsign-compare -Wno-format-nonliteral -Wendif-labels -Wstrict-prototypes -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wno-system-headers -DHAVE_CONFIG_H
#########################
# Build the libcurl library
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
include $(LOCAL_PATH)/lib/Makefile.inc
CURL_HEADERS := \
    curlbuild.h \
    curl.h \
    curlrules.h \
    curlver.h \
    easy.h \
    mprintf.h \
    multi.h \
    stdcheaders.h \
    typecheck-gcc.h \
    types.h
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(addprefix lib/,$(CSOURCES))
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := \
    $(LOCAL_PATH)/include \
    external/openssl/include \
    external/zlib
LOCAL_CFLAGS += $(common_CFLAGS)
LOCAL_COPY_HEADERS_TO := libcurl/curl
LOCAL_COPY_HEADERS := $(addprefix include/curl/,$(CURL_HEADERS))
#LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := libz
LOCAL_MODULE:= libcurl
include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)
```

Comment: That's gr8. Now getting errors due to 32 bit and 64 bit and openssl , But the answer is working for the question that I asked. " uncomment the BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY part , remove all part with creating executable curl " IMP input. Thanks for early , prompt responses , and clearing the doubts. :) Upvoted and accepted your answer :)