# Multiple file rename in Android

Tags: android, shell, scripting

I'm trying to write a script using Android's shell to rename all files of a given extension to add the .bak extension, and another to remove it.

This works for adding the .bak extension to all pdf files in the directory

```
ext=.bak
for f in *.pdf
do
  mv $f $f$ext
done
```

But bash string slicing using `${varname:index:length}` doesn't work in the android shell, so I'm at a loss as to how to remove the extension. Does anyone have any ideas?

EDIT: to clarify, I'm trying to find a way to delete the last four characters of a string in android shell. Other solutions that I have not considered which will solve my specific problem are also welcome.

UPDATE:
Based on the given answer, the following code will remove a file extension from any file possessing that extension in a current directory in an unmodified Android shell (where .bak can be replaced with the extension of your choice)

```
for f in *.bak
do
    mv $f ${f%.*}
done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried removing the substring

```
fname="test.abc.bak"
mv $fname ${fname%.*}
```

Thanks

Comment: ${varname:index:length} doesn't work, so I suspect android shell doesn't have this capability, but I'll try it.

Comment: It works!!! Could you point me to a reference for string manipulation using this technique?

Comment: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html#PSUB2 I found this resource on bash regular expression, and this seems to be valid in Android shell. I still haven't thought of how to do string indexing in general, but this solves my problem! Congratulations, bounty awarded.

Comment: I've updated the question to hold code based on your reply. Thank you again, this has solved a major issue for me.

Comment: this link http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/07/bash-string-manipulation/ is which led me to that answer. and you're welcome

Answer (score 0):

I got some code, but it uses temporary file, just try it and check for your usefulness

```
ls -l |awk '{print $9}' >/list
cat /list |while read line
do
echo $line >/tempfile
first=`cut -f1 -d'.' /tempfile`
echo $first >>/output.txt
mv $line $first
done
```

Comment: That would work, if android had awk and cut, which it does not.

Comment: PowerShell is a Windows terminal utility, as far as I know. I'm not very well-versed in Windows. I don't think PowerShell scripts will be helpful for Android.

Comment: See this if found helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8384213/android-ndk-revision-7-host-awk-tool-is-outdated-error  and this http://awk4j.sourceforge.net/home_en.html

Comment: The first is related to the host's awk tool, not android native (which doesn't exist), and trying to get awk4j running on Android is kind of overkill for this. I could write a separate Android app to do this as well, but a script using the built-in shell would be much more convenient/portable/versatile